# How to draw a line on MKMapView showing the route a user has taken?

Tags: iphone, gps, mkmapview, mkoverlay

I have had a look around online to try and find out the best way to draw a line showing the route a user has travelled. I think I need to use the MKOverlayView, and I guess I need to collect a selection of data points to plot (would these be GPS coordinates?). The question I have is based on how I would draw the line and keep adding to it as the users location updates?

I also want to be able to clear the line when a user presses a button. How would I implement this (not the button press, just the code to clear the line off the map view)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673303/how-to-draw-arc-curve-line-with-mkoverlayview-on-mkmapview

Comment: Also look at Apple's [Breadcrumb sample app](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Breadcrumb/Introduction/Intro.html) which does most of what you describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using MKPolyline. At First you need to get coordinates of route, then draw polylines over it. You will find an example [here](http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-draw-an-mkpolyline-on-a-map-view/) to draw polyline over some coordinates.