# Looking for an MKOverlayPathRenderer example

Tags: ios, ios7, mkmapview, mapkit, mkoverlay

I am trying to figure out how to use a new `MKOverlayPathRenderer` class.

In my app I previously used `MKOverlayPathView` when building with iOS 6 SDK,
but it does not seem to work with iOS 7 SDK unfortunately.

So I am trying to move my app from `MKOverlayPathView` to
`MKOverlayPathRenderer`, but have no success so far.

`MKPolylineRenderer` works OK, but `MKOverlayPathRenderer` does not.
The code gets called, but no overlay is drawn on a map.

Does anybody have a working example for `MKOverlayPathRenderer`?

Comment: There's a good example here including a curved line instead of solid line: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61573384/4260691

Answer (score 8):

First you have to make sure that you set `lineWidth` and `strokeColor`

```
polylineRenderer.lineWidth = 8.0f;
polylineRenderer.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Then In your renderer class, you have to override `-(void) createPath` method

```
-(void) createPath{
    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    BOOL pathIsEmpty = YES;
    for (int i=0;i< polyline.pointCount;i++){
        CGPoint point = [self pointForMapPoint:polyline.points[i]];
        if (pathIsEmpty){
            CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, point.x, point.y);
            pathIsEmpty = NO;
        } else {
            CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, point.x, point.y);
        }
    }

    self.path = path; //<—— don't forget this line.
}
```

if you want custom drawing, you would like to override this

`-(void) drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale inContext:(CGContextRef)context` method.

Comment: I am also trying to use MKOverlayRenderer, could you offer some advice on my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20558591/animated-gif-not-working-in-mkmapview-overlay-using-mkoverlayrenderer?noredirect=1#comment30789828_20558591

Comment: Even after self.path = path; self.path is still NULL